# Can't get the list of input radio

Tags: angular, angular6

I have this mapping   User   *-------------------------1    Profession

```
export class User
{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    profession: Profession;
}

export class Profession
{
    id: number;
    libelle: string;
    selected: boolean;
}
```

I want to create a user, bellow are the required files:

**create-user.component.html** is:

```
<div *ngFor='let item of array;let i = index'>    
        <label>                
            <input type="radio" [checked]="item.selected" (change)='radioChecked(item.id, i, item)'>
            <span></span>
            <span class="check"></span>
            <span class="box"></span>
            {{item.libelle}}
        </label>
    </div>
```

**create-user.component.ts** is:

```
array: Profession[] =
    [
        {id: 1, libelle: "Engineer", selected: true},
        {id: 2, libelle: "Student", selected: false},
    ];

    radioChecked(id, i, pro)
    {
        this.array.forEach(pro=>
        {
            if(pro.id !== id)
            {
                pro.selected = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pro.selected = true;
            } 
        })

        this.userService.getProfessionById(id).subscribe(data =>
        {
            console.log(data);
            pro = data as Profession;

            localStorage.removeItem("ProfessionLibelle");
            localStorage.setItem("ProfessionLibelle", pro.libelle);

        },error => console.log(error));

        this.selectedProfessionRadio = localStorage.getItem("ProfessionLibelle");
        console.log("------- Profession: " + this.selectedProfessionRadio + " -- " + i + " -- " + id);    
    }
```

**user.service.ts** is:

```
getProfessionById(id: number): Observable<Object>
    {
        return this.http.get<Profession>(`${this.baseUrl}/users/professions/id/${id}`);
    }
```

Once accessing to the interface create-user, the list of profession's libelle cannot be loaded as discribed by [image: this screenshot] 
As you see:

- For the first time, the list is empty (case 1).
- But after clicking on one input radio, the list will be loaded as expected (case 2).

Could you please tell me what I missed ?.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi Missar and welcome to SOF. Please read the article on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now, your example is not complete so we can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hello Sir Viqas, It's done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Missar It's seems working fine. Can you look at [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6amq6z) for code and [output](https://angular-2cbyzb.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks a lot for your reply. But that is it. I can't know what's the problem. the number of point radio is correct, but the libelle(Engineer, Student) cannot be shown except after the click of one point radio.

Comment: It looks like the code is correct. Try restart your pc.